mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
I am trying to debug my codeigniter 1.0.0 app code using phpstorm and xdebug with Docker. Both Phpmyadmin and Adminer containers are able to connect to mysql on another container, but codeigniter container cannot. I have tried all solutions given to similar questions on SE, but have hit a deadend. I would appreciate if someone can point out what could be wrong.
Here's the docker compose file:
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-files:/var/lib/mysql-files
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bitnami_blr
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - blrappci
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxxx
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 314572800
    networks:
      - blrappci
  # adminer
  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: adminer:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8088:8080'
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mysql
    networks:
      - blrappci
  # php-cli /usr/local/bin/php
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
    volumes:
        - ./apps:/opt/bitnami/apps
        - ./php-development.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-development.ini
    networks:
      - blrappci
networks:
  blrappci:
volumes:
  db_data:

My codeigniter database.php file:
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'bitnami_blr',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

I am getting the following error:
Severity:    Warning
Message:     mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Filename:    /opt/bitnami/apps/blrappci/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 203

All help is appreciated.
Updated:
ping and curl to mysql:3306 both worked fine. Also,
php -r 'var_dump(mysqli_connect("mysql", "root", "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "bitnami_blr"));' 

also worked fine from command line.
However, when I run the following code in Phpstorm using Docker PHP interpreter, it returns php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.
var_dump(mysqli_connect("mysql", "root", "sV2YjaI5s2Wa", "bitnami_blr"));

What is the right config to run php-cli in phpstorm within docker context?

Can you make sure the mysql container doesn't crash?

'hostname' => 'mysql' - Is there actually a computer called mysql inside your network?

why you give  like this 'hostname' => 'mysql',you try with 'hostname' => 'localhost' or ipaddress

mysql is the Docker container name

Are you able to ping mysql from app - docker exec -ti app ping mysql? Please add the contents of the dockerfile for app to your question.

Yes, I can ping mysql container from app container.

Make sure the container of mysql is running, if it's running you can go inside the app container by using below command:
docker exec -it app sh

then try hitting the mysql container by using ping command or curl command
ping mysql
curl mysql:3306 -vvv

if you see it's getting the IP of the container that means it's connected fine and your network is also fine.
if is not, check the network policy on your docker-compose.

ping and curl both worked fine. Also, php -r 'var_dump(mysqli_connect("mysql", "root", "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "bitnami_blr"));' also worked fine from command line.

However executing the same php statement in Phpstorm —  var_dump(mysqli_connect("mysql", "root", "sV2YjaI5s2Wa", "bitnami_blr")); — returns 'php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known' error.

@Zero Executing this from PHPStorm means accessing the container from your local machine, right? So it can not find your mysql container name. As you've already mapped port 3306 to the outside, you need to access localhost instead of mysql from your local machine.
